# jQuery Ajax call within ASP.Net to SharePoint 2013 REST Service (cross-domain) ACCESS DENIED

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, rest, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 site and an ASP.Net site. I added some jquery to my ASP.Net site to call a REST svc from my SP2013 site using the $.ajax jquery method. I get "Access Denied" in jquery-1.4.1.js line 4984 when it calls xhr.Open. I'm using IE8 (I believe all of my customers will be using IE8 as well).

Is this something that is resolved in a more recent version of jQuery?

Is there something I can do at the IIS level (thinking app pool configuration..?) to alleviate this?

Any clues?

Could SP.RequestExecutor be of use or is that just for SP Apps and not really for using with ASP.Net sites? more- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clue : jsonp and http://tipila.com/tips/83/allow-cross-domain-javascript-calls-in-iis-7

Comment: @Steve thanks- I'm playing with that but it seems like either SP2013 doesn't like jsonp or something else fishy is going on. i get "parsererror" when using jsonp.

Comment: I had issues too with jsonp Mime type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this a bit more and discovered that the "parsererror" was because SP 2013 REST returns an RSS ATOM feed, not a json feed. When setting dataType to xml it will parse it properly, then you can use the "entry" nodes to get to the items where the important data is within "m:properties" node. So to sum this up, dataType = xml, and you will need cors=true for cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dataType `jsonp` for cross-domain request and dataType `json` for same domain-same origin request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "otherdomain.com",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: "",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also as well as the JSONP thing to work around the likely cross-domain issue, it's worth pointing out that with the exception of the search service, which has multiple endpoints, all of the REST services in SharePoint require authentication by default.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do [this post may offer some useful pointers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites.aspx)

Comment: I'm leaning towards authentication being the key issue. Right now I am just running the ASP.Net site through VS (not iis) so is it passing some funky credentials that SP throws a fit with, not my credentials? Could this be solved if I pushed this to IIS with a dedicated app pool that used the identity of an authenticated user?

Comment: It won't help in this case since you'll be running on the client side. It would work if you moved the REST call into your asp.net server code, maybe using a REST service on there that acts as a proxy to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a cross domain issue. You can make use of CORS (http://enable-cors.org/) or build a wrapper web service on the same domain as your ASP.NET application that will call the REST service from your ASP.NET application.

Correct me if I'm wrong, JSONP will not be applicable here since REST sharepoint web services do not provide JSON response.

Comment: yeah i'm using cors. i really like your idea of using a wrapper web service! i will add that to the list if i can't get this resolved soon. SP REST should not have an issue providing json, I have consumed REST services from within the same SP site using $.ajax without a problem.

Comment: now I am seeing that I do get "parsererror" from the status return var when using jsonp as the method. my xhr returns a success, but i see it falls the the error callback and i see "parsererror" and "jQuery193812411111313etc.. was not called"

Comment: maybe sp 2013 rest doesn't support jsonp?

Comment: If you're using CORS you don't have to use jsonp since this should resolve the cross domain issue.

Comment: on your comment about the wrapper, did you mean "same domain as your SharePoint application" ?

Comment: that should be the same domain as your asp.net application. That way you don't have to deal with CORS.